# watch window in the debug is empty

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, watch

I was trying to understand how to fix my watch window but didn't find any good answer(I'm using visual studio 2013).

I used the debugger and suddenly the watch window didn't show the values or the object i'm have in the block - actually it didn't show anything anymore.
Does anyone know how can it be fixed?

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maby this will help you:

> To open the QuickWatch dialog box with a variable added While in break
>   mode, right-click a variable name in the source window name and choose
>   QuickWatch. This automatically places the variable into the QuickWatch
>   dialog box.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyzbs7s2.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I just added them one by one and know it works!

Comment: If this was the answer please mark it as answer. Glad I could help out.

Answer (score 0):

The Watch windows don't show anything by default, you need to add things to them to see the values. What might have happened in your case, is that either you deleted what you had by mistake, or you ran into a bug, where something got corrupted in your solution and they were lost.

If you want to see everything that is currently in scope, the Locals window is the way to go.

And if you want a superset of that (which has both current and previous statement), use the Autos window.

The QuickWatch dialog box is similar in concept to the Watch window, but QuickWatch can display only one variable or expression at a time

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx